# Similarity of Triangles in a Circle with Intersecting Chords To be Proven Using Sine Rule

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

Using sine rule and triangle similarity, please prove the theorem - When two chords intersect within a circle, the products of the intercepts are equal.

Hence, please prove Triangle Similarity using Sine Rule. Reference: https://amsi.org.au/teacher_modules/Circle_Geometry.html

Note: Just studying Circle Geometry for self-education purposes.

Here is a circle with Two Similar Triangles. [Similar Triangles in a Circle with Intersecting Chords](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJOPt.jpg)

Please prove Triangle Similarity using the Sine Rule.

It's a delight to provide additional materials to provide more context. Video (Intercepts in Two Intersecting Chords of a Circle) - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MwfD3_KCKgNt0pXaOcFcMrNMGkOMbRXJ/view?usp=sharing

Video Guide (Video Guide Using Congruent Angles in the same arc - Proof - The products of the intercepts are equal in an intersection of chords) https://drive.google.com/file/d/16Xfg1BR5sMCcsuU7plBbihGlVQ8IymRI/view?usp=sharing

Again, please prove Triangle Similarity using the Sine Rule. Thank you for the kind help.